# Does jQuery.load() make multiple HTTP calls for more than one element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, load

When using jQuery .load() with a class and there are multiple elements, does it make the HTTP call for each element? Or does it make the HTTP call and then use the result in each element?

`$('.element').load( url );`

If there are 3 divs with the ".element" class, are 3 HTTP calls made or one?

Comment: Look at the network tab and find out for yourself

Comment: Did not occur to me, so thanks!  It does, in fact, make the call for each element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does a request for each element.

But for issues like this you should really check the network tab of your developer tools!

Comment: The network tab shows that the HTML call is made each time for each element.  So I switched to $.ajax() with a callback to update the elements.

Answer (score 0):

I guess not, if you use .each IT will probably do.